# NFS storage write permissions

Tags: centos, nfs, network-share, windows-server-2016, file-permissions

I have installed NFS Server on CentOS 7. I have two other hosts, that I want to share different directories with. Here's my `/etc/exports` file:

```
/home/WS2016    192.168.200.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/home/debian    192.168.120.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

As shared directories' names hint, one is dedicated to Windows Server 2016, and the other to Debian 9 host.
Debian 9 only needs port 2049 (!) to be open for `sudo mount 192.168.120.2:/home/debian /mnt/nfs/storage`. R/W access works fine with just that port being allowed by `iptables`.
Windows Server on the other hand, can have at best R/O access through UNC (`\\IP\`) or Network Drive Mapping.
To know which ports are used, I `grep udp` from `rpcinfo -p`'s output and ignore dynamic ports. I am not sure about port 20048. Debian does not need it?

`111 portmapper
2049 nfs
2049 nfs_acl
20048 mountd`

So, I would like to know:

- Is it possible to leave just port(s) 2049/111 opened for TCP/UDP and have working R/W access via UNC path on Windows?
- If not, do I simply combine `-s 192.168.200.2` and `-m multiport --dports 111,2049,20048` flags in an `iptables` rule?

Quick UPD: here's `ls -la /home/` output from the NFS Server host

```
[root@server ~]# ls -la /home/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root      root       51 10. may 10.48 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root      root      242  9. may 22.07 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody  32 10. may 12.34 debian
drwxr-xr-x   2 nfsnobody nfsnobody  18 10. may 15.54 WS2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFSv4 requires only port 2049. It's unlikely that the mount being readonly has anything to do with which ports are open, provided you actually mounted the share with NFSv4. (And there's virtually no reason to use the ancient 1990s era NFSv3 or the prehistoric NFSv2. You should ensure that you aren't.)

Comment: I have figured it out with AnonymousUid/Gid in Windows registry.
I have also disabled `nlockmgr`. As soon as I enable iptables with only 2049 allowed, I see a lot of requests to 111 and 20048 in `/var/log/messages`. If I allow 111 for tcp/udp and 20048 for tcp it works. However ideally I'd find a way to only use 2049 for both Debian & WServer

Comment: @mekkanizer Sounds like your Windows client is still trying to use NFSv3.

Comment: You are correct, I have learned from the Internets that v3 is the default version for Windows Server 2016 NFS Client. 
Please tell me how do I set the version used (AFAIK WS2016 support NFS v4.1) and then check the used version (like with blank `mount` command)?